# Independence War 1 & 2 story considerations?

Tags: independence-war

Do I need to know anything about the plot of Independence War to enjoy IW2? I'm about to play the latter for the first time and have never played the former...

Comment: Do you mean I-War 2: Edge of Chaos?

Comment: @Armin - yep, that's the one

Comment: It is a great game. Don't forget to install the latest patch, and if you get stuck ( very probable ), consult the walkthrough.

Answer (score 2):

I-War 2:Edge of Chaos has it's own self-enclosed storyline. It is happening in the same "universe" about a 100 years after the first game. All you have to know about the first game is actually quickly mentioned in a narrative by one character surviving it.